# Using command line to add users and permissions to a SVN server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I shoudl set the permissions for a lot of users, each one having a different access to each project, in a SVN server. I would like to just edit the auth file in the server, but I would like to know if it is possible to add users and permission through the command line.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to manage access rules for Windows (Active Directory) accounts using these PowerShell cmdlets packaged with VisualSVN Server:

- [`Add-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Add-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Get-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Remove-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Remove-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Select-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Select-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Set-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Set-SvnAccessRule)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot, it is exactly what I needed. Is there something like this even for Apache?

Comment: @Maurizio and this one too. :)  You could upvote and mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful! Thank you.

Comment: @Maurizio Thank you!